# What are the steps to exclude Nuget packages from TFVC Source Control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I have existing .NET solution that is in TFVC source control.  When I added a nuget package, the packages folder and all it's contents were added to the project in source control.  In the future, how can I ensure that NuGet packages will not be added?

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, however the links you posted are unneeded. You should put your actual question here in your question section, then after you have made the question you should put the answer below.  Please try to describe what problem you are facing and what solution you need in the question section.  Your title is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a “.nuget” folder to the folder where the .sln file resides.  Open up Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, browse to that folder, right-click and choose New Folder.
2. Inside this folder, add a file named NuGet.Config.  To do this you’ll need to open up File Explorer and browse to the .nuget folder you just created, and create the file.  Add this to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
</configuration>
```

3. Add a .tfignore file to the folder where the .sln file resides.  You need to do this in File Explorer as well.  It’s a little tricky to add a file with only an extension like that.  You have to name it with a trailing dot like “.tfignore.”.
4. Finally, you need to add the .tfignore and the NuGet.Config files to TFVC.  To do this, open up Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, browse to the proper locations, right-click and choose Add items to folder.

Source:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control

**Note**:  The best practice is to not store the actual packages in source control.  Only the packages.config file should be checked in.  The packages.config file will allow any fellow developers who download the solution to *restore* the packages from the package source.

Comment: It's important to restart VS after adding the `NuGet.Config` and `.tfignore` files to TFVC. Otherwise, the changes won't take affect.  Here's a YT video showing the steps outlined above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfKcTX8NxAQ